# Using the Default Editor Kit to put text on system clipboard

Tags: java, swing, clipboard

I have been trying for a month now to reliably set the system clipboard in my program. Currently it works about 95/100 times. But I keep searching.

Yesterday I came upon this [the Java DefaultEditorKit.copyAction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DefaultEditorKit.CopyAction.html) and died a little inside seeing there was already something written that might do what I want.

Though the problem is that this is a "Action" for a dialog?

How can I issue the text I want copied to the clipboard? I do not wish to attach this "Action" to any button/component in my app. I want to be able to do

```
DefaultEditorKit.copyAction("Put this on Clipboard");
```

But this is undefined. I am not sure how to trigger this "action" and give it some text to work with?

EDIT: Here is my code that causes an exception.

```
public void setClip2(String arg)
{
    while(true) 
    {
        try
        {
            sysClip.setContents(new StringSelection(arg), null);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            try {Thread.sleep(20);} catch (InterruptedException e1) {}
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html

Comment: *How* do you currently set it? (the approach that works 95/100 times)

Comment: I use the clipboard.setContents("test") method (outline in Cyrille's answer). But for this method I must wait until setContents does not throw an exception. I do this by going into a while loop and just doing **continue** until no exception is encountered; usually about 1-2s. But if I do not wait long enough (sometimes up to 4 seconds) I fail to set the clipboard before I try to use the text I think I have set. (I will call the while loop, wait 4 seconds, then try to use the text on the clipboard, which sometimes is not there)

Comment: @BumSkeeter, how is that posted code compileable? Where do you invoke the code? How do you get your code to actually generate the Exception. As I told you in my posting the code I gave you NEVER generates an Exception so your looping code seems unnecessary. Unless you can tell us how you manages to generate the Execption we can't analyze the problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I just wondered if there was a way to reliably set the clipboard. (this method fails if you do not wait long enough trying to set it, which is usually about 1-2 seconds

Not sure why you have to wait to set the contents of the clipboard.

This program doesn't have any problem refreshing the clipboard every 200ms. That is the number increments by 1 every time is it displayed as expected:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.io.*;

class ClipboardLoopTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InterruptedException
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            //  add data to clipboard

            try
            {
                Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                StringSelection testData;
                testData = new StringSelection( "Test: " + i );
                c.setContents(testData, testData);

                //  Get clipboard contents, as a String

                Transferable t = c.getContents( null );

                if ( t.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) )
                {
                    Object o = t.getTransferData( DataFlavor.stringFlavor );
                    String data = (String)t.getTransferData( DataFlavor.stringFlavor );
                    System.out.println( "Clipboard contents: " + data );
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            Thread.sleep(200);
        }

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

I'm using JDK 7 on Windows 7.

Maybe you can post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This can still fail to set the clipboard to the desired text. If setContents() throws a exception then the clipboard will not be set for that i.-- What I mean by waiting for it to be set is, I go into a infinite loop while(true), and if an exception is thrown I do a **continue** else I do a **break**. This guarantees that eventually I will have set the clipboard to the desired text. I am trying to remove that eventually and make it a single line call. Ex. setClip(text) that does not throw an exception.

Comment: I tested my above code by running it in a window and also running Notepad. While in Notepad I was holding down the CTRL-C key to copy notepad text to the clipboard the whole time my program was running. I was never able to generate an Exception. So post your SSCCE that actually generates an Exception so we can see what your are doing. I tried the best I can but I can't generate an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

`DefaultEditorKit.copyAction` actually use (through some layers) the functionnality in java.awt.datatransfer. There you will find classes to send data to the clipboard.

Basically, if you just want to send a string to the clipboard without using any Swing component, you setup a `ClipboardOwner`, you create a `StringSelection` object and you give it to the system clipboard. Here is a most basic example:

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
clipboard.setContents( new StringSelection("Put this on Clipboard"), new ClipboardOwner() {

    @Override
    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard clipboard, Transferable contents) {
      System.out.println("I am no longer the clipboard owner.");
    }
} );
```

Comment: This is what I have been doing. Sometimes clipboard.setContents() fails to set the contents. (You have to put setContents in a try-catch) I just have this in a while loop, so if a exception is encountered it tries again until no exception is encountered. I just wondered if there was a way to reliably set the clipboard. (this method fails if you do not wait long enough trying to set it, which is usually about 1-2 seconds, though sometimes it works first try and takes < 1s.

Comment: The doc says `The method throws IllegalStateException if the clipboard is currently unavailable. For example, on some platforms, the system clipboard is unavailable while it is accessed by another application.` Is this what is happening to you? Anyway, look at the source of `DefaultEditorKit.copyAction()`, it's not doing anything fancier than this.

Comment: Yes that is what is happening to me. So the copyAction does the exact same thing I do basically. Just wait till no exception is thrown? (How does it know how long to wait?; Will it return before it successfully sets the clipboard?) **How can I see the source?**

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make myself clear: the copy action of the default editor kit will not loop until it works. It just tries once and provide an error feedback if it fails, I think.

Comment: If you get Oracle's JDK, you will find the source in the file `src.zip`.